# How do I start the OpenRefine Application in another Java Programm?

Tags: java, external, execution, openrefine

I am currently working on an application that is meant to start and stop different software applications independent of their implementation. Therefore, executable Files are added through simple Drag and Drop and executed on Buttonpress.
I already tried different approaches in Java such as Desktop.open(), Runtime.exec(), using ProcessBuilder or Apache Default Executor. While these approaches work fine for the most part, it seems that [OpenRefine](https://openrefine.org/) would neither open up with the OpenRefine.exe nor with the OpenRefine.bat file. Each time I click the button, nothing happends. I already checked if the execution through doubleclick or commandline works, but for some strange reason I can't get it running in Java. Do you have any additional suggestions to what I can try or what might be the issue with this specific application?

Here is a short sample for the ProcessBuilder Approach

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(String.valueOf(toolPath));
final Process process = processBuilder.start();
App.globalLogger.info("Started Tool with Process Builder");

InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Where toolPath is respectively the java.nio.file.Path of the File that I imported.

Comment: There's no hope of diagnosing your problem without seeing your code.

Comment: Not sure if a lot of code will help to evaluate the situation as it seems to be more of a problem with the OpenRefine.exe file, but nethertheless I posted a snippet from one of the examples I tried.

Comment: Does the application you're trying to open actually have an output stream that's usable?  Your approach will only work on console programs that use `stdout` for output.

Comment: I am not sure if the Outputstream of OpenRefine is important in this case, since I just want to start the application right now. However, while I don't get an error message, it also won't show up anywhere. Do you have any suggestions what I could use instead of the Processbuilder to avoid this issue?

Comment: The output stream of OpenRefine appears to be what your code is connecting to.  I suppose you could use the Unix equivalent of Task Manager (assuming you are, in fact, running on Unix or Linux) to check if OpenRefine is actually running, but without output the result isn't going to be particularly interesting.

Comment: If OpenRefine works on this system, the problem is unlikely to be anything to do with OpenRefine. You need to figure out what is different about the environment that your code is creating. A good first step would be to figure out what kind of error you are getting. It's also important to include all relevant details, like the operating system (Windows by the look of the .exe/.bat extensions), versions of Java, etc